# Как убрать подстроку из массива

Tags: c

Возникла проблема с функцией, она неправильно убирает подстроку из массива.
Есть массив в котором лежат символы нужные для генерации пароля. Выглядит так:

```
char alpha[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789#$%&@*^~"
```

И есть функция `remove_substr` которая убирает подстроку, например `0123456789`. Осуществляется перебор массива и подстроки. По условию пытаюсь распознать цифры и поставить вместо них нулевый байт

```
void remove_substr(char *substr)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < strlen(substr); j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(alpha); i++) {
      if (substr[j] == alpha[i]) {
        alpha[i] = '\0';
      }
    }
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  remove_substr("0123456789");
  printf("%s\n", alpha);
  return 0;
}
```

После того как функция отработает вывод получается таким:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Цифры и специальные символы были убраны, а нужно было убрать только цифры. Как сделать так чтобы убирались только цифры? А специальные символы остались нетронутыми
Заметил если поставить цифры после специальных символов в массиве alpha, то всё работает правильно

Еще я пытался писать так:

```
void remove_substr(char *substr)
{
 char *match = alpha;
 match = strstr(match, substr);
 *match = '\0';
 strcat(alpha, match);
}
```

Но здесь тоже убираются и цифры и специальные символы

Comment: printf() просто обрубает вывод при нахождении нулевого байта, поэтому, скорее всего, вам придется создать новую строку в функции и вернуть уже ее

Comment: `strlen` же до нулевого символа размер берёт, да и в любом случае стоит сохранить этот размер 1 раз, а не вычислять на каждой итерации. Ну и вы ничего не убираете, а заменяете одни символы другими по сути

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать с помощью `memmove`

```
char alpha[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789#$%&@*^~";
void remove_substr(char *substr)
{
  int len_alpha = strlen(alpha);
  int len_sub = strlen(substr);
  for (int i = 0; i < len_alpha; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < len_sub; j++) {
      if (alpha[i] == substr[j]) {
        memmove(&alpha[i], &alpha[i + 1], len_alpha - i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Помог этот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457608/how-to-remove-the-character-at-a-given-index-from-a-string-in-c)